# Using Private Setters or Work in the Constructor

Tags: java, class, exception

I have the following Book class:

```
    public Book(String bookTitle,ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,String> authors, String bookType ) throws InvalidDataException{

        this.setBookTitle(bookTitle);
        this.setAuthors(authors);
        this.setType(bookType);

    }

    private void setBookTitle(String title) throws InvalidDataException
    {  if(title == null || title.length() < 1){
            throw new InvalidDataException("Must Provide Book Title");
        }
        this.bookTitle = title;
    }

    private void setAuthors(ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,String> authors) throws InvalidDataException
    {   if(authors.isEmpty()){
            throw new InvalidDataException("Must Provide At least one author");
        }
        this.authors = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,String>(authors);
    }

    private void setType(String type) throws InvalidDataException
    {
        if(type == null || type.length() < 1){
            throw new InvalidDataException("Must Provide Book Type");
        }
        this.bookType = type;
    }
```

Should I have my constructor call the setter methods(I like this approach, as it's organized, and easier for me) or check the variables in the constructor and throw exception if needed and remove the setter? I would then have the make the variables `final`. Which approach is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is fine,

But you can make use of already existing frameworks to throw your exception,
ie Spring Annotations like @NotNull, @NotEmpty, @Valid etc.

You will realize they are giving you what exactly you are doing in a more elegant out of the box way. :)

eg

```
    public class Book {

            @NotEmpty(message="please fill author")
            pirvate String author;
            @NotEmpty("message="please fill title")
            private String title;
            @NotNull(message="you get my drift ;)")
            private Map<K,V> someMap;

            public Book(String author,String title, Map map){
               this.author = author;
            //blah blah no need for the setters...
            }

// blah blah other getters and setters

 }
```

[link](http://springinpractice.com/2008/07/17/annotation-based-validation-with-the-spring-bean-validation-framework) for you to understand more :) also look into maven projects for java to handle your dependencies..trust me.

Comment: you;re welcome, do look into the link ive attached..and maybe marking answer ^_^

Comment: Done and Done. SO is telling me to wait 1 min.